# Is it Possible to get a result from this query?

Tags: sql, json, oracle

please review the query, trying to achieve nested json as result from database.

```
select JSON_OBJECT( 
           KEY 'objects' VALUE 
               (SELECT JSON_ARRAYAGG( 
                         JSON_OBJECT( 
                           KEY 'object_type' VALUE object_type, 
                           KEY 'object_name' VALUE object_name 
                         ) 
                       ) 
               ) 
         ) 

  from Table name;
```

(Tried above not getting what i need)

I'm trying to achieve nested JSON. Currently I'm using map and stream in Java to achieve and would like to know if I can get it straight from query.

Thanks

Comment: Please add a fiddle (DDL+data) and the result for this data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JSON_OBJECT()` function is not needed to be nested within `JSON_ARRAYAGG()` function for your case. So, consider :

```
SELECT JSON_OBJECT( KEY t.object_name 
                    VALUE JSON_ARRAYAGG( t.object_type ORDER BY t.object_name ) ) 
                    as objects
  FROM t
 GROUP BY t.object_name;
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=1c87c3fb7aede9980f48a97988845a84)</kbd>

<kbd>[Referance](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/adjsn/generation.html#GUID-B0FA4582-762D-4C32-8A0C-265142BD347B)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

Can't test but I think:

```
select JSON_OBJECT( 
           KEY 'objects' VALUE 
                       JSON_ARRAYAGG( 
                         JSON_OBJECT( 
                           KEY 'object_type' VALUE object_type, 
                           KEY 'object_name' VALUE object_name 
                         ) 
                       ) 
         ) 

  from Table name;
```